# how emulate "try with resources" for android

Tags: java, android

`try with resources` not available on Android,
if you want to target wide range of devices,
so I want emulate something like it, with such semantic:

1. No exceptions - close, and throw exception if close failed
2. Has exception - close and ignore close exceptions

Is such code suppose to work as I want or I missed something? And may be possible to simplify it in some way?

```
final Closeable closebale = ...;
try {
    //work with closeable
} catch (IOException e) {
    try {
        closeable.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        //log exception
    }
    closeable = null;
    throw e;
} finally {
    if (closeable != null) {
        //we not catch any exception
        closeable.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that it's "not available on Android"?  `try-with-resources` can be used if you're compiling with JDK 7 or above.

Comment: @JacobG. you missed this part `target wide range of devices`, you need API level 19 to switch it on

Comment: @JacobG. I mean Android API level 19, while default level 16, so it make my program not avaible for wide range of android devices. It looks like to implement this feature in android jvm require some changes in their jvm: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73483

Comment: https://github.com/yareally/Java7-on-Android

Answer (score -1):

The historical pattern in Java is:

```
Closeable foo = null;
try
    {
    foo = ...;
    ...
    }
finally
    {
    if (foo != null)
        { foo.close(); }
    }
```

You may put the call to `.close()` in a `try-catch` block if you wish to catch and either handle or suppress any exceptions that occur during the attempt to close the resource.  I recommend against suppressing exceptions.  At a minimum you should log them.

Comment: With such code, if we have exception inside `try`, and then `close` catch exception, then original exception was suppressed. And if unconditionally suppress `close` exception, then I missed exceptoin, if no exception inside `try`.

Comment: @user1244932  That is not true.  A `finally` block does not suppress the original exception.

Comment: I mean if in finally close throw exception, then original exception was suppressed.

Comment: @user1244932 As I wrote in my answer: _You may put the call to .close() in a try-catch block if you wish to catch and either handle or suppress any exceptions that occur during the attempt to close the resource._

Comment: PS. you can see this documented in the official JavaSE tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html  There's nothing new here, this is just how resource handling has been in Java during the decades prior to Java7.